# Evaluating and gathering results of conditions

Tags: haskell, if-statement, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I have a bunch of conditions which returns lists, is there a way of evaluating them without giving each condition a name?

Simplified example:

```
conditions i j = c1 i j ++ c2 i j ++ c3 i j

    where 
    c1 i j | i > 2     = ["x"]
           | otherwise = []
    c2 i j | j > 5   = ["y", "a"]
           | otherwise = []
    c3 i j | j > 10  = ["z"]
           | otherwise = []
    c4 i j | j > 10 && i > 1 = ["z", "c", "hello"]
           | otherwise = []
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define an operator for this:

```
infixl 1 *|

(*|) :: [a] -> Bool -> [a]
xs *| b | b = xs
xs *| b     = []

conditions i j = (["x"]             *| i > 2)
              ++ (["y", "a"]        *| j > 5)
              ++ (["z"]             *| j > 10)
              ++ (["z","c","hello"] *| j > 10 && i > 1)
```

It'a also possible to rewrite the last line as

```
++ (["z","c","hello"] *| j > 10 *| i > 1)
```

if this is desired for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
conditions i j = (if i > 2 then ["x"] else [])
                 ++ (if j > 5 then ["y","a"] else [])
                 ++ (if j > 10 then ["z"] else [])
                 ++ ...
```

Comment: `if b then [x] else []` == `[x|b]` which is perhaps nicer to look at, even if it might be confusing to someone who has never encountered it.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred one:

```
conditions i j = (guard (i>2)             >> ["x"]) ++
                 (guard (j>5)             >> ["y","a"]) ++
                 (guard (j > 10 && i > 1) >> ["z", "c", "hello"] )
```

List comprehension abuse:

```
conditions i j = [ x | i>2 ,             x <- ["x"] ] ++
                 [ x | j>5 ,             x <- ["y","a"] ] ++
                 [ x | j > 10 && i > 1 , x <- ["z", "c", "hello"] ]

conditions i j = concat ( [ ["x"]               | i>2 ] ++
                          [ ["y","a"]           | j>5 ] ++
                          [ ["z", "c", "hello"] | j > 10 && i > 1 ] )
```